# Are there vector graphics available of the mana symbols of magic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm looking for vector graphics of each of the mana symbols (normal, hybrid, phyrexian, 2-or-color). Where can I find them?

Comment: If you are trying to create custom cards, you might want to check out http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net/ also there used to be an MTG symbols font floating around (which could be used to get the vectors) but it seems to have disappeared from the 'net. Still looking for a place to download it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Slightly Magic](http://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4430&sid=a4157beb902583b681496f74398d506e) has most of them.

Answer (score 5):

[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/micku/mana-cost) has them. [Here](https://github.com/micku/mana-cost/raw/master/images/mana.svg) is a direct link to the SVG file. The readme says that it uses the ones from the Slightly Magic forum thread that user1873 linked to in their answer, but it also has the colorless mana symbol. [This post on the same forum thread](http://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4430&start=45#p201343) has the energy symbol.

I don't see any copyright information, so be careful. They are also protected by trademark.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a font of various magic symbols [here](http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/showthread.php?t=321284). Most vector graphics programs should be able to convert from the font to vectors.

Comment: How do you get the colors in there?

Comment: Depends on how you're using the fonts, what application are you using?

Comment: Good ol' html. Might prove problematic ;-)

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard, just use something like this `<span class="symbols"><span class="green">o</span>G</span></span>` where `.symbols` defines the magic symbols font, and `.green` defines the color for green. Here's a site that has some info on what the appropriate RGB values should be. There are other resources on the net too, like on the mtgsalvation forums, but I'm having a hard time digging them up. I think they're somewhat transient and might potentially be targeted by WOTC for takedowns.